# How to make highcharts can be drag in chart to select multi points in mobile phone

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile, web, highcharts

### Details description

- I make the high-charts can be drag in the chart and make the selected points marked.
- It work well in the PC browser.
- It can only click in the chart when visit the chart in mobile phone(android).

### Question:

How can i make it success in mobile phone that select multi points by dragging in the chart? Thanks.

Code in angularJS to select points by drag:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x',
                events: {
                    selection: function(event) {
                        return selectPointsByDrag(event);
                    },
                    click: function(event) {
                        return updateRelatedProjectsInfo([event.xAxis[0].value, event.xAxis[0].value], $scope.buildTimeInfo);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: chartConfig.parameters.title,
            tooltip: chartConfig.parameters.tooltip,
            xAxis: chartConfig.parameters.xAxis,
            yAxis: chartConfig.parameters.yAxis,
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    marker: chartConfig.parameters.areamarker,
                    cursor: 'Pointer',
                    events: {
                        click: function(event) {
                            //buildtime = buildtime;
                            return updateRelatedProjectsInfo([event.point.x, event.point.x], $scope.buildTimeInfo);
                        }
                    },
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: chartConfig.parameters.linearGradient,
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: chartConfig.parameters.marker,
                    lineWidth: chartConfig.parameters.lineWidth,
                    states: chartConfig.parameters.states,
                    threshold: null
                },
                line: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    cursor: 'Pointer',
                    events: {
                        click: function(event) {
                            return updateRelatedProjectsInfo([event.point.x, event.point.x], $scope.buildTimeInfo);
                        }
                    },
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: chartConfig.parameters.linearGradient,
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    marker: chartConfig.parameters.marker,
                    lineWidth: chartConfig.parameters.lineWidth,
                    states: chartConfig.parameters.states,
                    threshold: null
                }
            },
            legend: chartConfig.parameters.legend,
            series: chartConfig.series(cpuUtilizations, availMemories)
        });
```

and the function for selection event of highcharts is:

```
function selectPointsByDrag(event) {
        var highChart, k, l, len, len1, len2, m, point, ref, ref1, ref2, ref3, selectedPoints, selectedPointsEnd, selectedPointsStart, series, timeRange;
        if (!event.xAxis) {
            return;
        }
        highChart = event.target;
        ref = highChart.getSelectedPoints();
        for (k = 0, len = ref.length; k < len; k++) {
            point = ref[k];
            point.select(false);
        }
        ref1 = highChart.series;
        for (l = 0, len1 = ref1.length; l < len1; l++) {
            series = ref1[l];
            ref2 = series.points;
            for (m = 0, len2 = ref2.length; m < len2; m++) {
                point = ref2[m];
                if ((event.xAxis[0].min <= (ref3 = point.x) && ref3 <= event.xAxis[0].max)) {
                    point.select(true, true);
                }
            }
        }
        selectedPoints = highChart.getSelectedPoints();
        if (!isEmpty.isEmp(selectedPoints)) {
            selectedPointsStart = selectedPoints[0];
            selectedPointsEnd = selectedPoints[selectedPoints.length - 1];
            timeRange = [selectedPointsStart.x, selectedPointsEnd.x];
            return updateRelatedProjectsInfo(timeRange, $scope.buildTimeInfo);
        }
    }
```

Use this function to complish the selected multi points marked by drag in the chart.

Comment: sorry, it was a little mess by accident. i will post another later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make selecting multi points by drag in highcharts work in mobile phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397180/how-to-make-selecting-multi-points-by-drag-in-highcharts-work-in-mobile-phone)

Comment: yes, that is my question.